# Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I tried the following but it did not fix the issue:

1. I deleted `.metadata` and restarted eclipse, did not fix it.
2. I deleted `.project` and restarted eclipse, did not fix it.

If I changed my workspace, it would fix it, but I want to use this existing workspace.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the folder for the project still in the work-space directory? Also, please edit in your version of eclipse, it may be helpful info.

Comment: I'm running on eclipse Mars 2 version. I do not understand your other question.